# Why this does not exclude From Spring conf

Tags: spring-boot

I have such conf.

```
package com.data;

...

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.data",
    excludeFilters = {
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "scraping.*"),
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.data.DataGetter.AmazonSQS.*"),
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.data.Scraper.com.data.Scraper.LinkedInScraper")
    })
public class MinerApplicationWithProxyUserServiceEmulatingBrowserRabbit {
```

Why this conf still does not exclude and creates beans in second and third exclude filters?

Comment: Please show your package structure. It's very unclear what packages you have due to your packages not following naming conventions (they should be all lowercase!). So right now I'm clueless if `LinkedInScraper` is a package or not.

Comment: LinkedInScraper is a class. and other are packages.

Comment: And you're sure that `LinkedInScraper` is within a package `com.data.Scraper.com.data.Scraper` (so basically the same thing twice)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer already mentioned, a dot has a special meaning in a regular expression since it matches almost any character. Ironically, that means that your regular expression will also work, because a `.` in regular expression also matches a simple dot.

If you wonder why your first filter does work, well, that's because you defined the `basePackages` property to `com.data` already, so it's probably already excluded due to that.

That means that you should escape your packages properly, and that you can remove the first one from the filters because it's already filtered due to the base package:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.data",
    excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com\\.data\\.DataGetter\\.AmazonSQS\\..*"),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com\\.data\\.Scraper\\.LinkedInScraper")
})
```

> I'm using `\\..*` at the end because that will mean that zero to multiple characters after the last dot will be matched, rather than one character.

However, from your current code I can't explain why the other two filters do not work, because they **should**. This can only mean a few things:

1. You are having a different package-structure, for example:

   - Your third filter uses the `com.data.Scraper` package twice
   - Your third filter doesn't use `.*` at the end, which means that 
     `LinkedInScraper` is a classname, and not a package.
   - Your packages do not follow the naming conventions (should be all lowercase)
2. You have a different `@ComponentScan` elsewhere, that does include the other two packages.

Comment: I had have a different @ComponentScan elsewhere. Now I will just find out how to load only one of them.

Comment: @May by via @ConditionalOn* annotations?

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan You can use conditionals, profiles or just remove the other `@ComponentScan` and move over everything to the other one.

Answer (score 1):

For `REGEX` filter you will have to escape the DOTS (.) in regex value.

So your configurations should be something like,

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.data",
    excludeFilters = {
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "scraping.*"),
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com\\.data\\.DataGetter\\.AmazonSQS.*"),
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com\\.data\\.Scraper\\.com\\.data\\.Scraper\\.LinkedInScraper")
```

> I would really want you to try the `FilterType.ASPECTJ`. Its pretty
>   cleaner in terms of code.

Comment: FilterType.ASPECTJ does not support backshash.
type = FilterType.REGEX still does not work with \\

Comment: Each has their own way of defining patterns. Regex Filter takes a regex and ASPECTJ takes a pointcut expression.

Comment: Even though it's probably a mistake indeed, be aware that `.` matches almost any character in a regular expression. That means that his regular expression should have worked, and that the problem lies elsewhere, in code we can't see yet.

Comment: I'm planning on removing my answer. As it might mislead the users in future? Tell me if otherwise...

Comment: Even though in this particular example, it's caused by something entirely different, I think that escaping the dots in regular expressions when necessary is good information to keep.